# Write text under a form definition in python flask

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

I have a about page in my python flask website. I want to write some text under a form definition. My python app has a definition for the about page.

```
class Aboutpageshow(flask.views.MethodView):

    def get(self):
        return flask.render_template('about.html')
```

and linking

```
app.add_url_rule('/about',view_func=Aboutpageshow.as_view('aboutpage'),
             methods=["GET"])
```

And the html page definition is as follows

```
      {% extends "base.html" %}

      {% block content %}
      <h1>About</h1>
      <form method= action="{{url_for('aboutpage')}}">

      <p> my text here </p>
      </form>
      </br>    
      {% endblock %}

      {% block nav %}

      <li><a href="{{url_for('index')}}">back</a></li>
      {% endblock %}
```

In this process I want to write the text in this form space.

Comment: @Faisal_Amin you want to pass text from variable in template? <p>{{ variable }}</p> ?

Comment: @Faisal_Amin What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I just want to show some information on the page. No database connection, no Get or Post. Just like a simple about page in any website. Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 0):

```
class wtforms.fields.Field
```

Stores and processes data, and generates HTML for a form field.

I am not sure if you are talking about **placeholders** or **help text**, so i will say for both.

- The WtForms Form field takes description as one of the parameter
  which will work as helptext for you when you render forms.

  Refer : http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/fields.html
- In order to use placeholders with jinja2 templates, you have to use
  something like this in your jinja2 templates

  {{ demo.render(placeholder="abc")|safe }}

Comment: I just want to show some information like name, address etc. Just like a about us page. Nothing fancy.

Comment: No, just some information on my about page. When I click the about button it does not show the intended text I want to show. It goes to the page but does not show the information.